# MSO-specific CSS hack for Outlook HTML email?

Tags: html, css, email, outlook

There's a ton of IE conditional hacks (such as ending a style property with `!ie`, various uses of the * character, etc.).

I tried several of these in an inline style in an email sent to Outlook (2013), but they did not appear to work.

I tried `mso-width-alt:100%` but [what little documentation I can find](http://dev.bowdenweb.com/css/v/ms-office/ofhtml9/ofconStyleTable.htm) doesn't show it supporting percentages.

I also tried `!mso` just to see if it did anything, but it did not.

I'm wondering if anyone knows of any CSS hacks that can be used for Outlook/MSO inline styles?

---

More specifically, I have a table that needs to be `width:100%` in Outlook, but breaks in iOS so I'm using `min-width:100%`, which doesn't work in Outlook. I know I can wrap the table tag in a conditional and swap it out completely to make it work, but I'm trying for a more elegant solution if one exists.

Comment: Most of the question sounds like you're asking for resources, for lists of descriptions of Outlook-specific CSS features. Questions like that are frowned upon, so it's good that you end with a specific problem! Now in what way does the table break in iOS?

Comment: @MrLister There's a cell with a fixed width, and if the table width is set to 100%, that cell width appears to take over and overruns the screen width in the iOS mail client. In all other environments the cell width maxes out at table width, which is screen width at 100%, which gives me a nice responsive setup. I'd still prefer to know if there's a syntax which can be applied to MSO that other environments ignore, as that would be an elegant (if hacky) fix for many situations.

Answer (score 0):

Prepend property with `!`

```
<table style="!width:100%"></table>
```

Appears to affect MSO and IE<=7 only:

I am going to have so much fun with this.